# Mi consulta Left join no trabaja correctamente

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqli, mysql-workbench

Tengo la siguiente consulta en Mysql:

```
select If(substr(DigCent,-1) = '0', 'Presupuesto', If(substr(DigCent,-1) = '1', 'Ingresos Extraordinarios', 'Apoyos y Preasignaci\xc3\xb3n')) As 'Tipo',
        If(substr(DigCent,-1) = '0', 'Presupuesto', If(substr(DigCent,-1) = '1', 'Ingresos Extraordinarios', 'Apoyos y Preasignaci\xc3\xb3n')) As 'Cuentas',
        ImpPrev as 'Importe',
        (ImpPrev - SaldoPrev) as 'Ejercido',
        SaldoPrev as 'Saldo' FROM previos
        where tpomon=0 and  dependencia='211';
```

La consulta anterior me devuelve 556 registros. Quiero agregarle un `left join` con otra tabla de la siguiente manera:

```
select If(substr(p.DigCent,-1) = '0', 'Presupuesto', If(substr(p.DigCent,-1) = '1', 'Ingresos Extraordinarios', 'Apoyos y Preasignaci\xc3\xb3n')) As 'Tipo',
        If(substr(p.DigCent,-1) = '0', 'Presupuesto', If(substr(p.DigCent,-1) = '1', 'Ingresos Extraordinarios', 'Apoyos y Preasignaci\xc3\xb3n')) As 'Cuentas',
        p.ImpPrev as 'Importe',
        (p.ImpPrev - p.SaldoPrev) as 'Ejercido',
        Format(ifnull(cmp.ImpCargo,0.00),2)  as 'Comprometido',
        p.SaldoPrev as 'Saldo' 
        FROM previos as p  
    left join Comprometido cmp on concat(p.ClaveUpa,p.Ejer,p.tpomon,p.Numero)=cmp.Previo and cmp.activo = 1 and cmp.TipoEgre = 'CP'  
    where tpomon=0 and  dependencia='211'
```

Pero al hacerlo ya no me devuelve los 556 de la consulta original, me devuelve 708. Leí por ahí que puede haber diferencias si pongo los `ANDs` en la clausula `on` o en el `where`, asi que movi `cmp.activo = 1 and cmp.TipoEgre = 'CP'` a la parte del `where` y obtuve 161 registros. He intentado varias combinaciones pero siempre obtengo 161 o 708, ¿Por que no puedo obtener los 556 de la consulta original? ¿No se supone que `left join` debería devolver los registro de la tabla izquierda completa y poner los coincidentes de la derecha y si no encuentra coincidentes poner `null`? ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: `¿No se supone que left join debería devolver los registro de la tabla izquierda completa y poner los coincidentes de la derecha y si no encuentra coincidentes poner null?` es exactamente lo que hace un `left join` pero ¿qué ocurre si hay más de un coincidente en la tabla derecha? justamente lo que te esta pasando, se "duplican" y lo pongo entre comillas, por que no es realmente una duplicidad, simplemente se repiten los datos de la tabla izquierda por cada fila coincidente en la derecha.

Comment: Tenías razón, no había unicidad en el campo previo